# While solving differential equation, can $y_1$ be considered as $y?$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Tangent is drawn at the point $(x_i,y_i)$ on the curve $y=f(x)$, which intersects X-axis at $(x_{i+1},0).$ Now, again a tangent is drawn at $(x_{i+1},y_{i+1})$ on the curve which intersects X-axis at $(x_{i+2},0)$ and the process is repeated $n$ times, i.e. $i=1,2,3,...,n$. If $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n$ form an arithmetic progression with common difference equal to $\log_2e$ and curve passes through $(0,2).$ If curve passes through the point $(-2,k),$ evaluate $k$.

**Solution:**

Equation of tangent at $(x_1,y_1)$ is $$y-y_1=\frac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1)$$

It cuts X-axis at $(x_2,0)$, so, $$x_2-x_1=-y_1\frac{dx}{dy}$$

Given, $x_2-x_1=\log_2e$, so, $$-\frac{dy}{y_1}=\frac{dx}{\log_2e}$$

After this, in the book, they have replaced $y_1$ with $y$ and solved the differential equation. But isn't $y_1$ just a fixed point? How can we replace it with $y?$

Comment: Hm, I think the assumption should be that $x_2-x_1=\log_2e$ for any value of $x_1$. If we only care about $n$ points, there should be infinitely many solutions, right? Under my assumption, you can let $x_1$, and thereby $y_1$, vary.

Comment: @Milten I think that makes sense, thanks.